# Connecting VSCode and GCP

Tags: visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform

I have a google cloud compute instance that I connect to with

```
INSTANCE_NAME='sam_vm'
gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" $INSTANCE_NAME --project sam_project
```

when I try to connect with cmd-p then typing in that command, I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-central1-a" "shleifer-v1-vm" --project $hf_proj: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

How can I connect?

Answer (score 6):

run

```
gcloud compute config-ssh
```

then in the vscode remote-ssh popup,

```
ssh {instance_name}.{zone}.{project_name}
```

Comment: In case you're not sure about `ssh {instance_name}.{zone}.{project_name}`, this can be found in the config file that was updated by the first command: probably at `/Users/@user/.ssh/config`.

Comment: Hi Sam, when I try to do this the terminal shows: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname {instance_name}.{zone}.{project_name}`.  Same thing happens if I type that `ssh` command in Windows Powershell.  Do you happen to know how to deal with this?  I tried do `gcloud compute config-ssh` and `gcloud auth login` again, but afterwards same issue still prompts.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/71497597/2346618

Answer (score 1):

Even though it has been 2 years since this questions has been asked, I am providing instructions for those who are still trying to figure out how to set up ssh to GCP in VSCode on macOS.

Once you have [Google Cloud CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) installed and have been granted access to the VM instance, login to your Google Cloud account by running in terminal:

```
gcloud auth login
```

Setup following variables which will be used in gcloud commands:

```
gcloud config set project <your project name>

gcloud config set compute/zone <your GCP zone>
```

Then you can establish SSH tunnel between VM and your local machine:

```
gcloud compute ssh [YOUR-VM-NAME] --tunnel-through-iap
```

Setup VS Code and install [Remote Development extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack).
Run the following command in terminal to obtain internal SSH command used by `gcloud compute ssh` to connect to VM:

```
gcloud compute ssh [YOUR-VM-NAME] --tunnel-through-iap --dry-run
```

The output may look similar to following:

```
/usr/bin/ssh -t -i /Users/<User_ID>/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o CheckHostIP=no
-o HashKnownHosts=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.8972912327831725343 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes 
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/<User_ID>/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts 
    -o "ProxyCommand /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 
    /Library/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel <instance name>
    %p --listen-on-stdin --project=<your project name> --zone=<your zone> --verbosity=warning" 
    -o ProxyUseFdpass=no <Gcloud_Username>@compute.8972912327831725343
```

Copy this SSH command and remove `‘/usr/bin/’`:

```
ssh -t -i /Users/<User_ID>/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o CheckHostIP=no
    -o HashKnownHosts=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.8972912327831725343 -o IdentitiesOnly=yes
    -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes 
    -o UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/<User_ID>/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts 
    -o "ProxyCommand /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3 
    /Library/google-cloud-sdk/lib/gcloud.py compute start-iap-tunnel <instance name>
    %p --listen-on-stdin --project=<your project name> --zone=<your zone> --verbosity=warning" 
    -o ProxyUseFdpass=no <Gcloud_Username>@compute.8972912327831725343
```

In VS Code:

- Press 'Cmd' + 'Shift' + 'P'
- Select 'Remote-SSH: Add New Host'
- Press 'Enter'
- Select the config file `/Users/<User_ID>/.ssh/config`
- Press 'Cmd' + 'Shift' + 'P'
- Select 'Remote-SSH: Connect Host'
- Select Compute instance as Linux.

VS Code should establish SSH tunnel to the VM and you should be able to open root folder.

Hope that this will help someone save hours of efforts.

Answer (score 0):

First execute `gcloud compute config-ssh`

Open ~/.ssh/config file

Find

```
Host {instance_name}.{zone}.{project_name}
    HostName {ip_name_google_provided}
    IdentityFile /Users/youruser/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/youruser/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    HostKeyAlias=compute.123423
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    CheckHostIP=no
```

and convert to

```
Host {ip_name_google_provided}
    HostName {ip_name_google_provided}
    IdentityFile /Users/youruser/.ssh/google_compute_engine
    UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/youruser/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
    HostKeyAlias=compute.123423
    IdentitiesOnly=yes
    CheckHostIP=no
```

Simply use ip ({ip_name_google_provided}) at HostName as Host name and try to connect {ip_name_google_provided} as a solution.

Note: Problem is computer can not resolve DNS {instance_name}.{zone}.{project_name} from ssh config file.