# Connecting VSCode to GCP Instance via Remote Explorer and gcloud

Tags: ssh, gcloud, vscode-remote

I'm using VSCode on Windows and gcloud shell to try to connect to a GCP instance.

I used the `gcloud compute config-ssh` command to create the alias to connect to my GCP instance

I then added the `ssh <vm_name>.<region_stuff>.<project>-<project_id>` line generated from the previous gcloud step to Remote Explorer in VSCode where you enter the ssh line for the connection and choose the config file

I tried to connect with Remote Explorer, selected Linux for the remote machine's OS, and keep running into this error when the remote window opens:

```
[21:47:20.078] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[21:47:20.428] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[21:47:20.429] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[21:47:20.447] > ssh: Could not resolve hostname <vm_name>.<region_stuff>.<project>-<project_id>: No 
> such host is known.
[21:47:20.480] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[21:47:21.757] "install" terminal command done
[21:47:21.757] Install terminal quit with output: such host is known.
[21:47:21.757] Received install output: such host is known.
[21:47:21.758] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[21:47:21.759] Resolver error: Error: 
    at m.Create (c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:584145)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:582705)
    at t.tryInstall (c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:681555)
    at async c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:643798
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:647116)
    at async t.resolve (c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:644848)
    at async c:\Users\Vedant Gannu\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.100.0\out\extension.js:1:720590
[21:47:21.766] ------
```

Based on the error and the answer in [Connecting VSCode and GCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61178156/connecting-vscode-and-gcp/71497597#71497597) , I followed the solution by replacing host and hostname with the external IP address.

But is there a way to prevent having to do this everytime? Like the entire point of running and using the ssh from `gcloud compute config-ssh` is provide an alias and not have to keep readding the host when the IP changes, right? Is there something that can be done to prevent this and actually use the alias for connecting?